# is there any way for OData filtering when URL length exceeds the limit?

Tags: ajax, c#-4.0, kendo-grid, odata

In my application kendo grid is used. When I am filtering number of parameters  with odata I am not able to filter due to exceeds max length . what is the best approach for filtering data with GET method in ODAT.

Comment: can you use POST instead? That would be the safest solution, if your URL is getting too big.

Comment: Thanks ADyson. is there any reference to check this one ?

Comment: not sure what you mean? To check what?

Comment: I am just telling is there is website reference or blog  for looking this solution .

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't know those frameworks specifically (and anyway, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - unfortunately asking for recommendations is off-topic) but I do know that generally there is a restriction on URL length. I'm sure those tools must have documentation which would show you how to change the request method from GET to POST, it can't be too difficult.